# Как расположить элементы на графике правильно?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Всем добрый вечер.
Ломаю голову, не могу продумать алгоритм для [графика](http://alexeyno.bget.ru/d3/)
В чем, собственно, проблема
[скрин](http://joxi.ru/D2P0vDBTgk7j23)
Здесь видно, что у некоторых элементов x параметр одинаковый. 
У меня не получается продумать ф-цию для второго и последующего элементов. Если есть элемент с таким же параметром x - нужно рассчитать новый y (расположить его выше с небольшим смещением, примерно на 10px вправо)
Вот код основной в-ции расчета 
Код ф-ции

```js
function prepare(object) {

      var windowSizePX = 1140;
      var elemWidth = 20
      var countBlocks = windowSizePX / elemWidth;
      var blockValue = 1000;
      var blockSizePercent = Math.round((100 / countBlocks) * 1000) / 1000

      console.log(blockSizePercent, 'ele')
      var diapasonsArray = []

      // range diapasons
      for(var key = 0; key < countBlocks; key++) {
        diapasonsArray.push([blockSizePercent * key, blockSizePercent * (key + 1)])
      }
      console.log(diapasonsArray)

      // calculate percents
      for(var key = 0; key < object.length; key++){
        object[key].percent = object[key].sum * 100 / blockValue;
          object[key].r = 10
          object[key].y = 265
      }

      // remember block number for each element
      for(var key = 0; key < object.length; key++){
        for(var j = 0; j < diapasonsArray.length; j++) {
          if(object[key].percent >= diapasonsArray[j][0] && object[key].percent <= diapasonsArray[j][1]) {
            object[key].blockNumber = j
          }

          if(key !== 0) {
            if(object[key].test === object[key - 1].test) {
              object[key - 1].x = object[key - 1].blockNumber * 20
            }
          }
        }
      }
        return object
    }
```

Как можно рассчитать координату y?

Answer (score 0):

Хм. Я попытался подумать и придумал только такое решение. К сожалению я не головастый. Надеюсь более опытными люди знают более изящное решение.

А так вот мое решение.

```js
const a = [
    [5, 10],
    [5, 10],
    [5, 10],
    [10, 10],
    [12, 10],
    [10, 10]
  ];
  
const b = {};

a.forEach(function(el, index) {
  if (b[el[0]] && b[el[0]].value === el[0]) {
    el[1] += el[1] * b[el[0]].index;
    b[el[0]].index++;
  } else {
    b[el[0]] = {
      value: el[0],
      index: 1
    };
  }
});

console.log(b);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function update_y_pos( objects ){ //массив объектов с x и y.
  var offset = 10;  //на сколько сдвигать если дублируется x
  var x_vals = {};  //храним последнее значение y для каждого x
  for( var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++ ){
      var obj = objects[i];
      var x = obj.x; // берем значение x из объекта
      x_vals[ x ] = x in x_vals ? x_vals[ x ] + offset : obj.y; // если такой x уже видели то выставляет новое смещение, иначе берём значение y из объекта
      obj.y = x_vals[ x ] // обновляем значение y в объекте
  }
  return objects; //возвращаем все объекты
}

var obj = [ { x: 1, y: 1 }, {x:1, y: 1}, { x:2, y:1 } ]; 
update_y_pos(obj);
```

Comment: Не совсем правильно логика описана, из-за этого произошла путаница.
Вы объявили объект x_vals, f обращаетесь, как к массиву.

Comment: x_vals[ x ] = x in x_vals ? x_vals[ x ] + offset : obj.y;
Этот момент в принципе не работает

Comment: Поправил. Забыл добавить инициализацию `obj`.